# Mismatch between IDs from minidump_stalkwalk and dump_syms

Tags: google-breakpad

I am trying to use google breakpad, but I am facing a strange issue.
i am working in linux. I have my own library, my_lib.so, which I process with dump_syms and generates this symbol :

```
$ dump_syms my_lib.so|head -2
MODULE Linux mips 3BB485681467218D36EB2FF02287096C0 my_lib.so
INFO CODE_ID 6885B43B67148D2136EB2FF02287096C
```

I create the symbols directory with the appropiate subdirectories. I then generate a minidump for the program that uses a stripped version of my_lib.so, but when I try to process it with minidump_stackwalk:

```
0x77dce000 - 0x77e23fff  my_lib.so  ???  (WARNING: No symbols, my_lib.so, AC40136B433E5A68F66CCE8C2C2E6C250)
```

It is seaching for a differente ID, **AC40136B433E5A68F66CCE8C2C2E6C250**,  so it does not find the symbols. Why the mismatch?

Knowing that it searches for AC40136B433E5A68F66CCE8C2C2E6C250 I manually changed the tree directory in symbols, to match that one, just to test. I also changed the id inside the my_lib.so.sym file, and then minidump_stalkwalk does not complain about not finding the symbols, but still I can't see the stack trace.

Any ideas about this mismatch?

by the way, if I run readelf -n over the original library and the stripped one, I get the same GNU BUILD ID.

Comment: This google breakpad thing seems to be more of a joke than a serious tool. It is near to impossible to make it work with new compilers. Maybe try Crashpad instead.